# Are there any disadvantages against using qsub to run tasks all the time?

Tags: parallelism, qsub

When I'm running a task on a computer network? I've just started to realize that if I qsub *any* task, then the task won't hog up my terminal, and I can do other things on the same terminal (which is quite useful even if the task only takes a single minute to finish).

And then I run qstat to see which taks have finished and which ones haven't.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/qsub.html is a good explanation of qsub.

Comment: Which batch system is supplying your `qsub`? (Several call their submission command by that name.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these cases I'd rather open another terminal. What is the reason that you don't want to do that?

Downside of running qsub, is that you have to write a tiny script file for a trivial operation, which takes you some time. I don't know how many other users are working on the same network, but the purpose is meant as a scheduler for jobs of several users on the cluster. Especially if there are no free cores available, your simple job will end up in the queue, taking you more time.

Did you consider `screen` as an alternative? With `screen` you can start and pause a different session in the same terminal. The workflow would be like this

- working in the terminal
- `$ screen`
- your tiny jobs
- Detach screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>)
- working in the terminal
- `$ screen -r` (to resume)
- Check status of this tiny job
- `$ exit`
- And you're back

Comment: I have a query in this regard. Usually on the server , you login and you land on a terminal loginnode. When using screen to run jobs, let's say the job requires 15-20G of memory. On terminal login node this is difficult. Is there a way I can assign memory limit to screen? sessions?

Comment: @user3138373 I recommend asking this as a new question (if it is not already asked)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any advantage of using `qsub` over the standard `at`.  The `at` command will take a "script" and execute it *at* a specific time (like "now"), using your current environment.  Then you can check the status with `atq` or remove the job with `atrm`.

```
$ nohup ./myscript myargs & # put script in the background
# almost the same as
$ echo ./myscript myargs | at now # computer runs script independent of terminals
```

You do need to make sure that your `myscript` will not be looking for input.

Myself, I use `screen` in a single terminal session everywhere I go, as Bernhard suggests.  Open a new window (within `screen`), start the script, switch back to original `screen` window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any disadvantage to using `qsub` to background jobs that I typically would run interactively inside of screen.  If you have a cluster available, then this is an optimal solution.

Although we have a job scheduler available, for a long time I tended to use screen to background long-running jobs or achieve parallelism without a lot of qsub script-writing overhead.  Eventually, the limitations of this approach became apparent, and I wrote this qsub wrapper `qgo` to allow me to replace `&` and `screen` with `qsub`:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p qsubscripts

qsub -w $(pwd)/qsubscripts -d $(pwd) -M user@addr.com $@ -S /bin/zsh -
```

Note that I'm using my preferred shell (zsh) but of course you can remove this argument, or add others.  The use of `$@` allows for the inclusion of resource specifications like `-l ncpus=4` as needed.  Here's how you'd use the script:

```
echo 'command -a 23 -b zz' | qgo | tee jobids
```

The `STDERR.*` and `STDOUT.*` files will be written to `qsubscripts` in the current working directory.  The job ids are provided on `The working directory for the job is set as the`cwd` as well, which makes it easier to write these short scripts.